# how to know when mysql INSERT is finished (multiple connections)

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have a multiple db connection situation like this:

```
db connection 1: INSERT xyz
(very short time passes)
db connection 2: SELECT [looking for xyz]
```

Sometimes the `SELECT` finds `xyz` and sometimes it does not (because it is on a different db connection than the `INSERT`). If I put a `sleep(1)` after the `INSERT then the SELECT` always finds `xyz`.

For db connection 1, how can I make it wait until the `INSERT` has finished and the new row is available for `SELECTs` running on another db connection?

My table is `innodb`. The use case is inserting an authenticated session ID on connection 1, then redirecting to an authenticated page, and then when the request for the authenticated page comes in (on another connection) we look for the session ID to authenticate the request. It's okay if we slow down login a little and make it wait until the `INSERT` has completely finished, so that the authenticated session ID is available to other requests before returning.

Comment: you can check with the last insert id

Comment: What coding language do you use? And which driver?

Comment: is connection2 connects to same database server or slave/replica database.

Comment: @shakti: last insert id is on a per-connection basis. connection 2 will NOT see what connection 1's last insert was.

Comment: I'm using php. connection2 is on the same database. Each connection is serving a different http request coming into my site. The 1st is login, and the 2nd is a request for an authenticated page. Thanks, guys!

Comment: In my case it wasn't because of the database, but I made a mistake in my ajax query, and it was refreshing the page right away instead of doing it "onSuccess" . To others, if it's happening to you, double check you didn't do something wrong around it.

Answer (score 2):

First question, why do you have two different connections for the same user ?

If you really want to keep two sessions, you can play around with [table locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html).

Connection 1, send these sql statement :

```
LOCK TABLE mytable WRITE; -- mytable is know locked, nobody else can access it
INSERT xyz; -- insert data in database
UNLOCK TABLES; -- unlock the table, the rows ARE inserted
```

Connection 2 :

```
SELECT [looking for xyz]
```

If the connection 2 try to access the database before the connection 1 has unlocked the table, the connection will have to wait. When the table are unlocked, the row will be inserted, so the select will return the wanted result.

Comment: The connections are created by http requests to my site. During login I do this: (1) validate username/password, (2) if valid, generate session id and INSERT to the user sessions table and save it in a cookie, (3) then do a 301 redirect to the user's start page (an authenticated page). When the next http request comes in I see that it's a page that requires authentication. I grab the cookie to get the session id index, and then do a SELECT to look for it. This SELECT is on a different db connection because it is a new http request.

Comment: So are you saying that if I LOCK the tale, then INSERT, and then UNLOCK the table, that by the time the UNLOCK returns the data from the INSERT will have been flushed so that a moment later a SELECT on another connection will be able to find it?

Comment: I'm saying that since all statement are executed sequentially, the UNLOCK won't be executed before the INSERT is finished and while the LOCK is active, the second connection won't be able to access the database at all.

Comment: oh. well, here's my situation: connection 1: INSERT, then redirect to new url (301 redirect). Connection 2 (the 2nd http request, coming from the redirected url): SELECT, looking for the session id that the INSERT wrote. I need to put a pause of some kind after the INSERT to give it time to flush that data so that when that thread creates the next request (301 redirect), the next request has access to the inserted data. I can lock/unlock around the INSERT if that guarantees that the inserted data will be flushed by the time unlock finishes. Or maybe I should look at the FLUSH command?

Comment: Thanks, Krtek. I added the lock/unlock but still see the problem. Is it possible that the inserted row is in some queue, waiting to be flushed? If I force a 2 second delay after the insert (sleep(2)) then it works fine. the sequence is: Thread1: INSERT xyz, sleep(2), redirect to new url; then Thread2: receive request for new url, SELECT [look for xyz], find xyz and proceed. But if I take out the sleep(2) then it does not find xzy, even if there is a LOCK/UNLOCK around the INSERT. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant but I'm using innodb tables. Should I try FLUSH TABLES mytable after INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

Because the insert statement is a transaction; once your insert statement has finished, it is in the database; I assume these two connections to the databases are made using two different threads; and you are issuing both commands simultaniously (at which time, there is no xyz inserted yet.

given the use case you describe, i'm unsure if this should even go over two different database connections. however; should above all prove to be false; you might want to use a lock file or something to indicate the 'transaction' is truly finished.