# Read after write consistency with mysql and multiple concurrent connections

Tags: mysql, hibernate, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to understand whether it is possible to achieve the following:

I have multiple instances of an application server running behind a round-robin load balancer. The client expects GET after POST/PUT semantics, in particular the client will make a POST request, wait for the response and immediately make a GET request expecting the response to reflect the change made by the POST request, e.g:

```
> Request:  POST /some/endpoint
< Response: 201 CREATED
<           Location: /some/endpoint/123
> Request:  GET /some/endpoint/123
< Response must not be 404 Not Found
```

It is not guaranteed that both requests are handled by the same application server. Each application server has a pool of connections to the DB. Each request will commit a transaction before responding to the client.

Thus the database will on one connection see an INSERT statement, followed by a COMMIT. One another connection, it will see a SELECT statement. Temporally, the SELECT will be strictly after the commit, however there may only be a tiny delay in the order of milliseconds.

The application server I have in mind uses Java, Spring, and Hibernate. The database is MySQL 5.7.11 managed by Amazon RDS in a multiple availability zone setup.

I'm trying to understand whether this behavior can be achieved and how so. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233879/how-to-know-when-mysql-insert-is-finished-multiple-connections), but the answer suggesting to lock the table does not seem right for an application that must handle concurrent requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under ordinary circumstances, you will not have any issue with this sequence of requests, since your MySQL will have committed the changes to the database by the time the 201 response has been sent back. Therefore, any subsequent statements will see the created / updated record.

What could be the extraordinary circumstances under which the subsequent select will not find the updated / inserted record?

1. Another process commits an update or delete statement that changes or removes the given record. There is not too much you can do about this, since it is part of the normal operation. If you do not want such thing to happen, then you have to implement application level locking of data.
2. The subsequent GET request is routed not only to a different application server, but that one uses (or is forced to use) a different database instance, which does not have the most updated state of that record. I would envisage this to happen if either application or database server level there is a severe failure, or routing of the request goes really bad (routed to a data center at a different geographical location). These should not happen too frequently.

Comment: "your MySQL will have committed the changes to the database by the time the 201 response has been sent" -- Is this guaranteed by MySQL? I can not find documentation for such behavior. Does committed mean than any subsequent read *must* get this result or that it *could* get it assuming REPEATABLE READ consistency.

Comment: Repeatable read has nothing to do with this, since you said that the transaction is committed before the 201 response is returned. MySQL documentation says on commit that, "A COMMIT means that the changes made in the current transaction are made permanent and become visible to other sessions." (source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html). There are no ifs, nor buts. Obviously, if the MySQL server happens to fail between the commit and the get request, then the updated data may not be available (it may even be lost forever).

Comment: Please excuse my nitpicking. I really hope you are correct. However, in the statement "A COMMIT means that the changes made in the current transaction are made permanent and become visible to other sessions." I'm missing the word 'immediately'. Rewriting the on-disk data structure can be costly. Does MySQL ensure this happens before the COMMIT returns to the client?

Comment: But it does not say 'not immediately' either. So, you are just playing with the words. If you do not trust mysql, then do not use it. Btw, it does not matter when a commit is written to disk because innodb picks the actual version of the record in a new read, no matter where it is stored. Each transactional db engine can be configured when the memory version is flushed to a disk.

Comment: I'm sorry if I come across as twisting the words. I have an issue in production where the logs indicate that the commit is not always immediate. I don't know what the root cause is and I'm not saying that MySQL is at fault here. I'm just trying to rule out every possible cause. Will try to make a minimal demo stack + stress test next to reproduce.

Comment: Then why are you asking wide theoretical questions and not the specific one you are truly interested in? Commit is immediate when it returns. It is not immediate when it is issued because it may have to wait until locks are released.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MyISAM tables, you might be seeing the effects of 'concurrent inserts' (see 8.11.3 in the mysql manual).  You can avoid them by either setting the concurrent_insert system variable to 0, or by using the HIGH_PRIORITY keyword on the INSERT.